# How to load default check out form on specific country in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, forms, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I don't want to load my custom checkout form on specific country detected. Is there anyway to do so. Following is my code.

```
if($config['applicable-countries'] =='all'){

            load my custom check out form;

}
else if($config['applicable-countries'] =='speific country'){

                load default check out form;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)

```
<?php
  if($config['applicable-countries'] == 'all') {
    get_template_part( $slug, $name );
  }

  else if($config['applicable-countries'] == 'speific country') {
    get_template_part( $slug, $name );
  }
?>
```

Or you can use a simple PHP include-

```
<?php
  if($config['applicable-countries'] == 'all') {
    include_once "checkout.php";
  }

  else if($config['applicable-countries'] == 'speific country') {
    include_once "checkout.php";
  }
?>
```